# How to acknowledge someone beloved in a publication for his/her support in writing the manuscript?

Tags: publications, acknowledgement

Is there a way to acknowledge girlfriend/wife or boyfriend/husband for his/her support in editing a Manuscript that got accepted with a great impression? I mean to say that he/she had re-written the manuscript.

One reviewer has commented "English of the manuscript is very clear and is very well written".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The authors would like to thank Jane Doe for her assistance in the preparation of this article.

or some variation of the sentence above.